# Find the specific HTML id inside a Jquery Selector call

Tags: jquery

I am currently using the `id^` jquery selector to find every element that starts with a certain phrase in its id for an autocomplete method. However, within my function, I want to access the specific id for when I select the option in order to bind it to the correct text box. I've tried things like `this.id` or `$(this).id` but neither seem to work. The code looks like this:

```
$('[id^="skill_name-"]')
.autocomplete({
    source: function(request, renderChoices) {
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            url: "",
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token,
                q: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(this.id)
                var skill_array = new Array();
                {% for skill in skill_listing %}
                    var name = ("{{ skill.name|escapejs|safe }}");
                    if (((name.substring(0,(request.term).length)).toLowerCase() === (request.term.toLowerCase()))) {
                      skill_array.push("{{skill}}");
                    }
                {% endfor %}
                renderChoices(skill_array);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#skill_name-new").val(ui.item.value);
    },
```

Comment: Could you show us some html as well?

Comment: `this.id` or `$(this).prop('id')` *should* work

Comment: I know you are using the `context` option, but have you confirmed that `this` is the element you expect it to be?

Comment: Could you do `console.log(this)` before the `$.ajax` line? Just to confirm what `this` is?

Comment: `this.element` seem to be what you're looking for, but since the API doesn't explicitly expose it I don't know if using it it a good idea.

Comment: Looks like this.element did the trick, returned an array with the id in it. Weird but works.